# boost::lockfree queue of Eigen::MatrixXf

Tags: c++, boost, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to create a `boost::lockfree::queue` following this example : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html

I could successfully create it for int (integer data type). However I have difficulty creating a queue for Eigen::MatrixXf. The queue is declared in `SolveDGEM.h`.

```
boost::lockfree::queue<Eigen::MatrixXf> q_cam0;
```

I getting following compiler error which I cannot comprehend

```
In file included from /home/eeuser/ros_workspaces/HeloRosProject/src/visensor_dgem/include/SolveDGEM.h:38:0,
                 from /home/eeuser/ros_workspaces/HeloRosProject/src/visensor_dgem/src/dgem.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::lockfree::queue<Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >’:
/home/eeuser/ros_workspaces/HeloRosProject/src/visensor_dgem/include/SolveDGEM.h:76:45:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:86:1: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’ 
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::lockfree::queue<Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >’:
/home/eeuser/ros_workspaces/HeloRosProject/src/visensor_dgem/include/SolveDGEM.h:76:45:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:90:1: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’
```

Answer (score 5):

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html:

> T must have a trivial destructor

Which is not true for `Eigen::MatrixXf`.